# Tooltip in reactive-table column header stops working when sorting the table based on that column

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm creating a table using the [reactive-table](https://github.com/aslagle/reactive-table) package and running into an issue with adding a tooltip to the title. Basically I'm trying to have a [tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) in my [column title](https://github.com/aslagle/reactive-table#setting-column-headers) that way when a user puts their cursor over it a little bit of information about the column will popup. Here is what I have to make this work:

```
{ key: 'example',
  label: function () { 
    return new Spacebars.SafeString('<span data-toggle="tooltip" title="This is some example text for the tooltip!">Example Title </span>'); 
  }
},
```

To initialize the tooltip:

```
Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function() {
    // Tooltip
    $("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip();
});
```

When I first refresh the page it works exactly as it should and when I put my cursor over the title the tooltip appears. The issue I am having is when I click on that title to sort the table rows based on that column, when I do this the tooltip stops working. I can click on any of the other column titles and sort the table rows based on those and it will still work, but when I click this one with the tooltip it causes the tooltip to not work anymore unless I refresh the page.

Any ideas on why this would be happening or how I could fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using a template for my label and putting the tooltip inside of that rather than using a function. I then placed the tooltip initialization JS inside of that template.onRendered.

Example:

.html

```
<template name="myColumnLabel">
    <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="This is some example text for the tooltip!">Example Title</span>
</template>
```

.js

```
Template.myColumnLabel.onRendered(function() {
    // Tooltip
    $("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip();
});
```

.js (reactive table)

```
{ key: 'example', label: Template.myColumnLabel }
```